# How to determine if statement is a tautology, contradiction, or contingency

Tags: logic

I've tried numerous ways at solving this problem but am stuck.

I believe I need to use logical equivalences involving conditionals, De Morgan's law, associative law and distribution (I've used them below, however most likely incorrectly). Here is the question and a way I've tried solving it. I need to do this without the use of truth tables, by the way.

To be clear I'm trying to find out *if the beginning statement is a tautology, contradiction, or contingency*. Thanks all!

$((p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot r)) \to (r \to p) \equiv$

$\lnot((p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot r)) \lor (r \to p) \equiv$

$\lnot((p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot r)) \lor (\lnot r \lor p) \equiv$

$\lnot((p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot r)) \lor\lnot ( r \land \lnot p) \equiv$

$\lnot(((p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot r)) \lor ( r \land \lnot p) )\equiv$

$\lnot((p \lor q) \land ((\lnot q \lor \lnot r)) \lor ( r \land \lnot p) ))\equiv$

---

And I seem to get stuck in here when trying to use the distributive property to perhaps evaluate one of these statements to true/false.

Comment: Aren't truth-tables a nice tool for this?

Comment: After the 3rd line, you have to "move inside" the leftmost negation sign using De Morgan.

Comment: @drhab Yes, but I need to know how to do this using logical equivalences as well.

Comment: A second possibility is to rewrite it as : $[(\lnot q \to p) \land (r \to \lnot q)] \to (r \to p)$ and use the fact that [Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism#Formal_notation) is a *tautology*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I based my answer on your first comment and didn't read your second one before posting, but it is way more straightforward. I think you should turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @Mauro ALLEGRANZA told in the comments, you should go back to your third line.

$$\begin{align}\color{red}{￢}((p \lor q) \land (￢q \lor ￢r)) \lor (￢r \lor p) \\
\end{align}$$

From there, we'll use De Morgan rule on the first $\lnot$

$$\begin{align}\color{red}{￢}((p \lor q) \land (￢q \lor ￢r)) \lor (￢r \lor p)\\ & \Leftrightarrow \lnot(p\lor q)\lor\lnot(\lnot q \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot r \lor p) \\ &\Leftrightarrow (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (q\lor r)\lor (\lnot r \lor p) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor q \lor \color{red}{r \lor \lnot r} \lor p \\
& \Leftrightarrow (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor q \lor \color{red}1 \lor p \\
& \Leftrightarrow 1 
\end{align}$$

The equation seems to show that you have a tautologie.

Let's verify it with a truth table.

(The table was too big to enter the page, so I had to introduce (A) and (B), I hope the notation is consistent)

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline p & q & r & (A)=p\lor q & (B)=\lnot q \lor \lnot r &  (A) \land (B) & r \implies p & (A) \land (B) \implies (r \implies p) \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\\hline
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\\hline
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline  
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
\end{array}$$